# Office 365: view all site which I'm admin

Tags: office365, sharepoint

My company buy Office 365, I'm a normal user, I created some sharepoint sites, I want to view all my created sites (as a list) but can't find nowhere to get it. Google return is "go to Office 365 admin page". 
So, how could I view a list of all sites which I'm admin in Office 365? 
I've tried to click on "Sharepoint" link on the top, nor the "Office 365" link but nothing show my sites.

[image: the homepage when i go to mycompany's Office 365's homepage]
[image: one of my sites]
[image: the site above doesn't showed up when I click on Office 365 too]

Comment: Typically only users with 'Full Control' or 'Manage hierarchy' can create sub-sites. If you need to find all sites you created then you'll inevitably need to use PowerShell to iterate over your site collections and then recursively iterate over the sites within each collection to output the site details when it identifies the author relating to your account. The GUI won't be very useful could you could potentially create hundreds, if not thousands of sites so PowerShell will be more effective.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to

> Admin Center > SharePoint  > Sites.

If you cant see the admin tile, you dont have administrative permissions to see all site collections.

And if you have administrative permissions,  then you cant see other SharePoint  sites.

Comment: I've add a screenshot of my Office 365 web page, there is nothing like "Admin Center"